# Sending form data without updating the HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkout

I'm using `jQuery`/`JavaScript` to append my cart items into the checkout form and

`item_name_x`, `amount_x` are dynamically generated.

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Orange">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Apple">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_3" value="Pineapple">

<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="260">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="140">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_3" value="600">
```

Here is what it will look like in the browser's developer tool.

[image]

Whenever I check or uncheck an item, the `HTML` within the developer tools will update accordingly. Is there a way to prevent the developer tools from updating but still be able to send through data?

Comment: You can go for using sessions if you want to hide your information

Comment: That's how it works with paypal. However, if you're worried about someone editing the amount, you shouldn't have any problems as long as you validate the payment after its been made.

Comment: What are you trying to actually accomplish / prevent?

Comment: @DelightedD0D like Wes Foster said the main reason I want to prevent people from manually editing the value in the developer tool, because it seems that manually changing the value and checkout works too.

Comment: It seems payPal may have APIs for this, have you looked at [Securing Your PayPal Payments Standard Buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/encryptedwebpayments/), specifically [Creating Protected Payment Buttons on the PayPal Website](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/encryptedwebpayments/#id08A3I0N30Y4)?

Comment: @DelightedD0D Thanks for the link, I will take a look now